# Laravel - Trying to get data via One To Many Relationship

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I haven't worked with Laravel in quite some time and now I'm trying to get back, working on a project but I'm hella confused with retrieving data over a one to many relationships.

In the usermodel:

```
public function blackboard()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Blackboard::class);
}
```

In the blackboardmodel:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

In the Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $blackboard = Blackboard::all();
        
    return view('home', ['blackboards' => $blackboard]);
}
```

In the view:

```
<ul class="list-group">
    @foreach($blackboards as $blackboard)
       <li>{{ $blackboard->user->name }}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

In the blackboard migration:

```
Schema::create('blackboards', function (Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->text('title')->nullable(); //Need to take out
    $table->text('content')->nullable(); //Need to take out
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('created_by'); 
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('created_by')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('users')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

In the user migration

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Somehow it doesn't let me display the user information via the blackboard data, I get errors such as:

```
Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: /var/www/html/intranet/resources/views/home.blade.php)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside you `Blackboard` model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'created_by', 'id');
}
```

If you want the reverse relationship to work too, inside your `User` mode:

```
public function blackboard()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Blackboard::class, 'created_by', 'id');
}
```

Don't forget to load the user in Controller before you reach the view, this will increase performance:

```
public function index()
{
    $blackboard = Blackboard::with(['user'])->get();
        
    return view('home', ['blackboards' => $blackboard]);
}
```

Comment: cheers mate, appreciate the quick help :D works flawless now

Answer (score 0):

i think that all you have to do is to provide the foreign key name, you can omit it only if you follow laravel convention (if you name it user_id):

in User Model:

```
public function blackboard(){
        return $this->hasMany(Blackboard::class,'created_by');
    }
```

in Blackboard Model:

```
public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'created_by');
    }
```