# Retrieving records from table given id from another table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I want to retrieve all `places` where `parent_place_id = 999` in the `attractions` table. What relationships would I set up and what would this query look like?

I've tried using the ["Has Many Through"](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationship, but I'm not sure if this applies, as my relationship is between two tables, not three.

I have a table `places`, with columns:

| id | place_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 999 | New York |
| 2 | 1000 | Miami |
| 3 | 1001 | Houston |

And a second table, `attractions`:

| id | place_id | parent_place_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 | 999 |
| 2 | 1001 | 999 |

Comment: If you have three table, ```Has Many Through``` does not apply here. Instead, use [One To Many.](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel - Trying to get data via One To Many Relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63863579/laravel-trying-to-get-data-via-one-to-many-relationship)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
class Place extends Model
{
    public function attractions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Attraction::class, 'parent_place_id', 'place_id');
    }
}
```

```php
class Attraction extends Model
{
    public function place()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Place::class, 'place_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Then you can call it with a method like this:

```php
$places = Place::whereRelation('attractions', 'parent_place_id', 999)->get();
```